# How can I condition the activation of a bind ('<Enter>') event to a certain area of ​a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class Right(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master.bind('<Enter>',self.mouse)
        self.master.bind('<Leave>',self.inmouse)
        self.lbl_77 = Label(self, text= 'Hellow', bg= 'green', fg='black')

    def mouse(self, event): 
        self.lbl_77 .place(x=90, y=0)
    def inmouse(self, event):
        self.lbl_77 .place_forget()

root = Tk()
frame = Right(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I have tried with the code seen above is to make the label with the message "hello" visible only when the mouse pointer rests on the window and remove it when it leaves it. My question is if I can delimit an area to be divided into the window so that only if it rests on it the event of showing the label is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an approach, it uses the `<Motion>` event to track the motion of the mouse and it also returns a Motion object which has attributes of `x` and `y` which allows to locate where the mouse currently is:

```py
        self.master.bind('<Motion>', self.mouse)
        self.lbl_77 = Label(self, text='Hellow', bg='green', fg='black')

    def mouse(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        x1, x2 = 0, 50
        y1, y2 = 0, 50
        if x1 < x < x2 and y1 < y < y2:
            self.lbl_77.place(x=90, y=0)
        else:
            self.lbl_77.place_forget()
```

Then it is a matter of simply setting boundaries of where to check for mouse and use a simple `if statement`. The complete code would look like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label


class Right(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master.bind('<Motion>', self.mouse)
        self.lbl_77 = Label(self, text='Hellow', bg='green', fg='black')

    def mouse(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        x1, x2 = 0, 50
        y1, y2 = 0, 50
        if x1 < x < x2 and y1 < y < y2:
            self.lbl_77.place(x=90, y=0)
        else:
            self.lbl_77.place_forget()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
frame = Right(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

A few other details is to `.pack()` (or `.grid()`) the frame and make it expand and fill the maximum area (because you use `.place()`), also probably set the window geometry to something so that you don't have to resize yourself.

Imports suggestion:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

PEP 8 suggestion:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestion. Your answer resolved the question I asked. Although the code is well defined, it brings with it new questions. I hope someone can answer me. Thanks . `<Motion>` solved the problem but when removing the mouse pointer from the window (activation area) with speed, the label is still visible.

Comment: It occurs to me to use the function: `after` and` DoubleVar` to update event.x but it works badly with `self.master.bind ('<Button-1>', self.return)`, because `def return (self ) `permanently positions the label when clicking on the same trigger area of `event.x` and there seems to be a conflict between `event.x` and` self.return`. because the label blinks

Comment: I understand that the label stays if you move the cursor quickly out of the window entirely? Well bind the `'<Leave>'` event that will simply `.place_forget()` to the `self`: `self.bind('<Leave>', lamda e: self.lbl_77.place_forget())`

Comment: It worked great thanks. Binding the `<Leave>` event to the frame and not to the parent window worked fine.